# Problems with a PHP include from the command line (or cronjob)

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, cron, system-administration

I am trying to setup a cronjob on my AWS EC2 instance. There is nothing wrong with the actual entry in the crontab file but when I try to run the command in the command line I get this response.

```
PHP Warning:  include(../scripts/connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../scripts/connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  include(../scripts/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../scripts/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 7
```

I can load this page in my browser and it works fine, but not from the command line (or cronjob).

Comment: Why don't you try to actually read the error messages?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I have, i have explained that i have checked that the file exists. And also that this script works when run from the browser

Comment: You can avoid those include errors by **always** using **absolute** filepaths. And set a default timezone at the top of your script. My only question is why it can't connect to MySQL.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois The problem is that the error log is saying that it could not locate the connect file. Although i know it it there

Comment: Use absolute filepaths. Problem solved.

Comment: Are the permissions good for your files? That can also prevent PHP fron including files.

Comment: @thatidiotguy If the permissions weren't good, PHP would throw a permissions denied error, not a "No such file or directory in ...".

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path to the files that you want to include

Answer (score 0):

Look to this path: /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php
I think there is no emailnotifications.php file. So this file is not included. If this file is not included there will be another errors

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:-

```
include(require dirname(__FILE__) .'/../scripts/connect.php');
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../inc/function.php';
```